# Tomcat 8.5 on Windows vs startup.bat issue

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, jasper-reports, barcode

I have a very specific problem deploying a webapp on a Windows installation of Tomcat 8.5 ( version 8.5.29 ) that I have been pulling my hair out for the last few days with no success. My web application generates a PDF using JasperReports and within this PDF is a barcode ( which uses Barbecue 1.5-beta ). Running this report on my local install of Tomcat works great, but when I deployed it to the server it did not produce the barcode. I did not see any errors either

[Barcode just has placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8A1a.jpg)

I downloaded the 8.5 distro without all the Windows specific installers and files, fired up tomcat (startup.bat) and ran the report again. This time it worked. The barcode rendered and everything. Same exact web app directory and config files.

I copied every file from the generic distro to the windows Tomcat install directory and ran again. Same problem. I went into the Tomcat Config dialog, changed the start up mode from jvm to java, but no luck.

The java virtual machine setting is:
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\server\jvm.dll

I changed it to use default and still the same problem. The java options are out of the box settings ( same when I ran the startup.bat ).

My only guess is the tomcat.exe that is being run is doing something different, but I cannot even begin to figure out what the difference is. I removed the tomcat native dll (tcnative-1.dll 1.2.16 ), but again no luck.

I feel like I need to just run the generic Tomcat 8.5, but this needs to be running all the time and run as a service.

I can't believe one stupid barcode is causing me so much pain. Its for a warehouse packslip so it is required. At this point I am willing to drive to the warehouse and just manually draw the barcodes myself!

Perhaps someone out in the internet has experienced this and has an idea before I just end my career and become a juggler.

Comment: "I can't believe one stupid barcode is causing me so much pain. " Wellcome to the club ;) On the server, is the Tomcat service running with a specific account ? Do you run the generic distro with this same account ? My questions are related to permissions, maybe you guessed that, we'll check later if it is about printers or anything else like prerequisites that you are not aware of.

Comment: I suggested tag : windows-service ; it's up to you

Comment: yeah its all under the same account. Its basically a fresh instance set up for me to install everything so I have free reign. When I run the bat file I am doing it from a command prompt without admin privileges. I am not  Windows guru, but I wonder if the permissions are different when installing via the installer. I should check that

Comment: if you copy the startup line from the service and put it in a command window, does it start and work ?

Comment: is there anything in the event viewer ?

Comment: you magnificent person you made my day! the startup line from the command window made it work. So there must be some permissions thing going on perhaps

Comment: Edit your Question by adding the Windows version. Maybe, change some tags to give more visibility to the Windows guys of SO (I'm not Windows expert myself)

Comment: Adding this property would maybe make Tomcat tell you where is pain : -Djava.security.debug=all . But I can't be sure, and it will produce a huge amount of log. It can be funny to try, if we are able to debug without the Windows guys' help.

Comment: your suggestion did solve my problem. After I ran it from the command line, I went and changed the Log On settings in the Tomcat configuration to my account instead of "local system account". That made everything work, so  Eugène Adell, I have you to thank for a solution.

Comment: You're wellcome dude. Please post an answer and mark it as the good answer. It will help other guys. Beware that running with your own account will break the service when you change your password. In Production, we create a service account usually.